# Delete inside foreach with linq where

Tags: c#, .net, linq, where-clause

I can see why this is not allowed:

```
foreach (Thing t in myCollection) {
   if (shouldDelete(t) {
      myCollection.Delete(t);
   }
}
```

but how about this?

```
foreach (Thing t in myCollection.Where(o=>shouldDelete(o)) {
   myCollection.Delete(t);
}
```

I don't understand why this fails. The "Where()" method obviously isn't returning the original collection, so I am not enumerating round the original collection when I try to remove something from it.

Comment: There is something i dont get about this "Thing" thing. Its certainly not a built in type thing is it? somebody enlighten me....

Comment: Sorry if the question was confusing. Thing could be any class at all and myCollecion is any ICollection<Thing>. FWIW Eric has completely understood and answered my original question so it's closed as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> I don't understand why this fails.

I assume your question then is "why does this fail?" (You forgot to actually ask a question in your question.)

> The "Where()" method obviously isn't returning the original collection

Correct. "Where" returns an `IEnumerable<T>` which represents the collection with a filter put on top of it.

> so I am not enumerating round the original collection when I try to remove something from it.

Incorrect. You *are* enumerating the original collection. You're enumerating the original collection *with a filter put on top of it*.

When you call "Where" it does not eagerly evaluate the filter and produce a *brand new copy* of the original collection with the filter applied to it. Rather, it gives you an object which enumerates the original collection, but skips over the items that do not match the filter.

When you're at a store and you say "show me everything", the guy showing you everything shows you everything. When you say "now just show me the apples that are between $1 and $5 a kilogram", **you are not constructing an entirely new store that has only apples in it**. You're looking at exactly the same collection of stuff as before, just with a filter on it.

Answer (score 13):

Try use this code

```
myCollection.RemoveAll(x => x.shouldDelete(x));
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do:

```
myCollection.RemoveAll(shouldDelete);
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually wanted to do something else inside the loop so Likurg's suggestion was better for me, but I have +1'd you :-)

Comment: ... if the type of `myCollection` has a RemoveAll method!  `List<T>` does, but many collection types do not.

Answer (score 6):

The second statement returns a `IEnumerable<>` operating on your list. This one should be okay:

```
foreach (Thing t in myCollection.Where(o=>shouldDelete(o).ToList()) {
   myCollection.Delete(t);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is the solution I have implemented, but I marked Eric as the answer because what I really wanted was to know what was happening  underneath

Answer (score 2):

It is because collection should not be modified withing the foreach loop. It attempts to delete it before entire foreach loop is executed. Hence it will fail.

Comment: I think you are close with the second part of your answer... are you looking for lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 1):

Where extension method filter the collection values based on the passed predicate and returns IEnumerable. Hence can't modify the collection while iteration.

You can use RemoveAll() for your purpose.